# Missing favourite star while reading posts

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

I tried the android app and so far I don't see any bugs etc, maybe one crash but I miss button for saving questions.

If this is multiple "question" I apologize for spamming. Would you please add it? Thank you.

Comment: This is already possible, see linked post.

Comment: Aww thank you. I expected it in the same place as it is on the web. Next time I should look for questions not create duplicates. And look harder for something I want.

Comment: No worry, nothing wrong in asking and having duplicates. You can leave this question here, it helps others find the info they need faster.

Comment: I hesitate whether to delete my question but I am not sure because I think that many people will expect star like I did. It is hard but maybe some tutorial or.. Maybe I am just blind.

Comment: Don't delete, enjoy the 5 rep you got. :-)

Comment: Duplicates can be good - if you've not found the original when typing this question up then the form of words you used is sufficiently different to mean others may have the same problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd like to give 5 stars on google, but app started crashing like crazy :-/ Ok, I get it.. keeping it.